# can i use same controller for user and admin?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am making a online book store in codeigniter.when user logging in, i am using

```
 localhost/folder/index.php/User_controller.
```

my qustion is when admin is logging in one extra menu should come for approval, rest of the view is same as that of user.so what should i do,when i make  seperate controller in different application folder,i have to run different in url, ie `localhost/foldername/admin.php/admin_controller`
.i am really confused.please help............

Comment: can  i go to one controller from another controller

Comment: i want like this if((username="admin")&&(password="admin")) go to localhost/foldername/admin.php/admin_controller for users loggin go tolocalhost/foldername/user.php/user_controller is it possible,admin view contains one extra menu bar rest of the view same as user

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom library where you may write function for checking `if_admin()`. After that you can use this function in any view file or controller and load content as required.

[Create Custom Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

So doesn't need to create different controller for admin. Just check with `is_admin()` in menu to load extra menu.

A demo method is look like (in custom library)

```
public function is_admin() {
    $type = (int) $this->CI->session->user_type;
    if ($type === 4) {//4 is admin type
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now check in view file as

```
if($this->custom_lib->is_admin()){
   //load extra menu items
}
```